# Sticky footer is moving along with screen while scrolling in ionic2+bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, angular, css, ionic-framework, bootstrap-4

i am using ionic2 with bootstrap to make PWA. I had used "My Ionic Material Design" theme.

I am facing problem to implement Sticky footer. I had tried with bootstrap code but problem is the Sticky footer moving along with screen. How can i Fix it always in bottom of screen. Anyone Please Help.

```css
.footer {
     position: fixed;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: red;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
  <div class=" bar footer bar-footer">
    <p>Bootstrap Footer</p>
  </div>
```

[image]

I'm using this code with "My Ionic Material Design" theme. but its had not fixed. problem is the 'Sticky footer' moving along with screen while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use footer the you can use the `ion-footer` tag which is given in the ionic. The `ion-content` has scroll and if you apply styles for footer the footer will not be in the fixed position. so better use the `ion-footer`

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Footer</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Refer ionic documentation [Footer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/toolbar/Footer/)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I tried with suggested code but footer is not sticking on screen it's always coming in bottom.  I want to Create sticky footer.

Comment: Please suggest any other idea to fix it.   Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qeYrwzHshn1sqz3jQGmn8X_hINOLMgLz/view?usp=sharing